# Flask-WTForms RadioField custom validator message doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

In `Flask-WTForms`, we can give a custom message for each validator for each field. But for `RadioField` it shows the default message only. Below is an example.

```
>>> from wtforms import Form, RadioField, TextField
>>> from wtforms.validators import *
```

**TextField**

```
>>> class MyForm(Form):
        x = TextField(u'Some text', validators = [Required(message="Hello")])
```

**Error Message**

```
>>> form = MyForm()
>>> form.x.data
>>> form.validate()
False
>>> form.errors
{'x': ['Hello']}
```

So for a `TextField` it shows the custom error message.

**RadioField**

```
>>> class MyForm(Form):
        x = RadioField(choices = [(1, '1'), (2, '2')], validators = [Required(message="Hello")])
```

**Error Message**

```
>>> form = MyForm()
>>> form.x.data
u'None'
>>> form.validate()
False
>>> form.errors
{'x': [u'Not a valid choice']}
```

The custom error message is not there. I guess, validation for `TextField` and `RadioField` will be different process and may be that's why it's showing the default message.

So my Question is How to show a custom message for the validation of a `RadioField`?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I tried to modify the source code but no solution yet.

Answer (score 5):

You are right about that the process is different.

So if you go do [source code](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/) there is base [`Field`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/fields/core.py#L23) class with [`validate`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/fields/core.py#L178) method. It's said

> ```
> """
> Validates the field and returns True or False. `self.errors` will
> contain any errors raised during validation. This is usually only
> called by `Form.validate`.
>
> Subfields shouldn't override this, but rather override either
> `pre_validate`, `post_validate` or both, depending on needs.> 
>
> :param form: The form the field belongs to.
> :param extra_validators: A sequence of extra validators to run.
> """
> ```

And the procedure of validation is `pre_validate()` -> `validate()` -> `post_validate()`(Call `pre_validate` -> Run validators -> Call `post_validate`)

As you can guess, `RadioField` has it's own `pre_validate()` method, but basically `SelectField`'s one. And then when `RadioField` is inherit from `SelectField` it has it too.

> ```
> def pre_validate(self, form):
>     for v, _ in self.choices:
>         if self.data == v:
>             break
>     else:
>         raise ValueError(self.gettext('Not a valid choice'))
> ```

So that's why you get `'Not a valid choice'` error instead of your custom one, on `wtforms.validators.Required()` validator, <del>because it just didn't go through the `pre_validate()` and it stops.</del>

*Note*: `Required` validator is depracated and will be removed in WTForms 3.0, and in [that](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/282) pull request they already removed it's usage. Instead of `Required()` validator, use `DataRequired()`

**UPDATE**: Since you add your validator to field you still should be able to get your error. Because since [`pre_validate()`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/fields/core.py#L470-L475) raises only `ValueError` it doesn't stop [`validate()`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/fields/core.py#L178-L214)

> ```
> # Call pre_validate
> try:
>     self.pre_validate(form)
> except StopValidation as e:
>     if e.args and e.args[0]:
>         self.errors.append(e.args[0])
>     stop_validation = True
> except ValueError as e:
>     self.errors.append(e.args[0])
> ```

And then it goes to

> ```
> # Run validators
> if not stop_validation:
>     chain = itertools.chain(self.validators, extra_validators)
>     stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)
> ```

And here is your validator exists and should add new error to the list of errors(`form.x.error`), however it converts `None` to `'None'`, so your `form.x.data` becomes `'None'`(`str` type), and now it goes to [`__call__`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/validators.py#L200-L208)

> ```
> def __call__(self, form, field):
>     if not field.data or isinstance(field.data, string_types) and not field.data.strip():
>         if self.message is None:
>             message = field.gettext('This field is required.')
>         else:
>             message = self.message
>
>         field.errors[:] = []
>         raise StopValidation(message)
> ```

And the condition `not field.data` is `False`, because `field.data` is `'None'`. 
Why data convert from `None` to `'None'` for `SelectField` and its related ones is explained in [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/289) and probably be fixed when [Pull Request](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/288) will be merged in master.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. I've replaced with `DataRequired( )` in my Code. But, How can I override the default message of `RadioField` Validation? Do I need to define a custom method?

Comment: @RatDon i've updated the question. There is nothing wrong with your approach, you still should be able to see your custom message along with the `'Not a valid choice'`. But things are little bit messed up with `SelectField` and its relatives. So for now one of your choices is to manually checking if `form.x.data` is `None`. Another one is to use [that fork](https://github.com/georgschoelly/wtforms/tree/no_coerce_none) that has [pull](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/288)

Comment: Got the source and modified as mentioned in that pull. But no effect. :-(

Comment: I still don't think they've yet implemented this nicely - https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/39